# Is there a way to specify more than two DNS servers?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

In my "Local Area Connection Properties", under IP Version 4, I can specify an IP address (or get one automatically) and specify a preferred and alternate DNS server.

**Is there any way to set more than just these two DNS servers?**  Our internal DNS is kind of flaky, and I'd like to be able to specify to use it, but to fall back on Google's DNS servers when necessary.  (I would just use Google's, but then I can't get to local network resources.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Seems to be possible in Windows 7](http://www.pctips3000.com/how-to-assign-more-than-two-dns-servers-to-a-dns-client-windows-7-computer/).  I don't really scope out anything behind the "Advanced" button very much; this comes as a surprise to me as well.  Perhaps someone else can confirm if this works in Windows XP.

Though you'd probably get better performance if you ran your own local caching-only nonauthoritative DNS server that would use your LAN's DNS server as a forwarder for LAN domains and Google or OpenDNS (or others) as a forwarder for anything else.  If you only use 1 or 2 hosts on your local LAN you can likely get by with setting your system's DNS to Google's and then have a few `hosts` file entries if the IP's aren't prone to changing much.

Comment: Beautiful!  I did have to enter the IP addresses of my local DNS at the top of the list, or else it took Google's to be the only ones.  But now it works fine.